# How do I validate the data by value in laravel's validator?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am wondering if there is an easy way to validate the data by value in Laravel 4's validator

something like this

```
$validator = Validator::make(['toolMode' => 'fastTool'], ['toolMode' => 'shouldBeSameAs:fastTool Or shouldBeSameAs:expertTool']);
```

so if there is something other than provide these two values it fails the validation

I know I can just do that with if else but just wanted to know if there is anything in the validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for the rule `in`:

```
$validator = Validator::make(['toolMode' => 'fastTool'],
                             ['toolMode' => 'in:fastTool,expertTool']);
```